# How is the active stake of a stake pool calculated?

Tags: stake-pool, staking

This question is related to my previous question: [When are the snapshots for the active stake in an epoch taken?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/1975/1142)

The active stake of a pool is used to calculate the rewards. What kind of system calculates the active stake of a stake pool? Is this done by the Cardano nodes or by the stake pools themselves or some other part of the Cardano ecosystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data captured by the snapshot is stored on-chain as a part of the ledger state, so all fully synchronized cardano-node instances have access to it. So, for example, when you run the **cardano-cli query stake-distribution --mainnet --out-file stakeDist.out** command the cardano-cli queries and outputs the current active stake data for each pool.

Comment: I think this answer is (partly) wrong: ledger state is not stored on-chain and nor are the stake snapshots that are part of it. Ledger state is kept in memory by the nodes and it is a result of folding (reducing) the blockchain.

Comment: Just a minor correction. These snapshots are part of ledger state and are not actually stored on the blockchain (They are too big. There is a new snapshot every 5 days and over 1 million stake addresses.). The are part of ledger state that can be recreated by replaying the block chain from genesis.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the active stake is calculated as a sum of all coins that were delegated to a particular pool. You can take a look [here](https://input-output-hk.github.io/ouroboros-network/shelley-spec-ledger/src/Shelley.Spec.Ledger.Rewards.html#reward).
[image]

[image]

Comment: So is this part of the nodes? Or is this shelly-spec-ledger part of some other system running in parallel? And if it's part of the nodes, which nodes are running this code? And who initiates the transactions/reward payouts?